# South African Rand Payment Processor

Tags: payment-processor

Does anyone know of a payment processor that integrates with Civi and also accepts South African Rand? We're finding out that most payment processors don't accept African currencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe offers ZAR so you could check that out - see https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#charge-currencies

We have Stripe working on several of our implementations but not had to try with ZAR yet.

Answer (score 3):

While Stripe can accept payments in ZAR, they are currently unable to payout in that currency. Thus, they effectively cannot support operations entirely in ZAR.